# How to store connected lists of different dimensions in database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to store ordered lists of voltages like this in a mysql database:

```
V1 = [[1123, 1109, 1107, 1115, 1122, 1107, 1109, 1121, 1121, 1120, 1123, 1103, 1139, 1132, 1115, 1143], [1133, 1115, 1085, 1115, 1127, 1089, 1102, 1095, 1108, 1115, 1089, 1104, 1105, 1107, 1107, 1140], [1093, 1123, 1084, 1091, 1115, 1085, 1083, 1098, 1115, 1092, 1098, 1115, 1098, 1081, 1122, 1115], [1094, 1115, 1109, 1108, 1102, 1142, 1090, 1089, 1081, 1105, 1096, 1095, 1089, 1104, 1115, 1126]]
V2 = [[1850, 1889, 1913, 1935, 1917, 1922, 1905, 1905, 1913, 1894, 1883, 1880, 1892, 1889, 1898, 1892], [1780, 1809, 1806, 1776, 1820, 1818, 1809, 1831, 1807, 1816, 1820, 1754, 1818, 1805, 1797, 1756], [1794, 1839, 1870, 1817, 1844, 1777, 1831, 1837, 1814, 1827, 1843, 1836, 1815, 1817, 1802, 1782], [1779, 1800, 1767, 1751, 1794, 1808, 1822, 1829, 1805, 1850, 1785, 1777, 1792, 1779, 1786, 1785]]
Vsum = [[1894, 1952, 1923, 1907], [1857, 1883, 1864, 1842], [1814, 1908, 1908, 1867], [1841, 1858, 1873, 1839]]
```

I will need to store a different set of lists just like these for around 25 unique IDs. The list above corresponds to a single module ID = 1. Each module is divided into 4 quadrants, with 16 channels each, or 4 groups of 4 channels each. Thus, I would hope to be able to find V1 for ID=1 by querying for `(ID=1, quad=#, ch=#)` or be able to find Vsum for ID=1 by querying for `(ID=1, quad=#, group=#)`

However, the issue I see with this is that Vsum is a voltage corresponding to a group, which is the sum of 4 channels. As a consequence, the last dimension of Vsum gets reduced by a factor of 4. This means that the columns storing the values don't all share the same unique "primary ID".

My cleanest vision would look like this:

```
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
| id | quad  | ch   | gr   | V1   | V2   | Vsum |
+----+-------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 |   0   |  0   | 0    | 1123 | 1850 | 1894 |
|  1 |   0   |  1   | 0    | 1109 | 1889 | 1894 |
|  1 |   0   |  2   | 0    | 1107 | 1913 | 1894 |
|  1 |   0   |  3   | 0    | 1115 | 1935 | 1894 |
|  1 |   0   |  4   | 1    | 1112 | 1917 | 1952 |
|  . |   .   |  .   | .    | .... | .... | .... |
|  . |   .   |  .   | .    | .... | .... | .... |
|  1 |   1   |  0   | 0    | 1133 | 1780 | 1857 |
|  . |   .   |  .   | .    | .... | .... | .... |
```

I would hope to avoid the redundancy in the final column, but I don't see a way to avoid that without creating a separate table. It would be unfortunate to split it up because all of this information is connected but I suppose one of the purposes of database normalization is to avoid duplicates where there shouldn't be. I won't try to fight adding in a second table, but I would like to know if there is a better alternative to that structure given the data I'm working with.

If splitting it up into two is the right way to go, do you have any specific advice for how to do it? This would be my first foray into database normalization, so I'm a bit of a novice at this stuff.

Comment: Is the value of Vsum determined by the V1 and V2 values in the group?  If so, and if the calculation is simple enough, you might be able to just calculate it at run-time.  If not, it's perfectly appropriate to pull Vsum into a separate table, since its key is different from the keys for V1 and V2.

Comment: Ah no, sorry it was a bit of a misleading variable name. I will plan to split it up pending no other responses.

Comment: Several thousand rows?  With some redundancy?  No problem.  "Normalization" is not a requirement; it is not even desirable in some cases.

Comment: I think that the redundancy becomes an issue for me here because I need a unique "primary key" for each of the `Vsum`s, but the way that the data is structured means that `(ID=#, quad=#, group=#)` may be unique for Vsum but it is not unique for V1 or V2 and thus can't function as a primary key if kept in a single table.